# Nested Do loops with externally defined iterators

Tags: list-manipulation, function-construction, evaluation, procedural-programming

I want to be able to define a set of iterators for nested `Do` loops, such as

```
asdf = {i[#], {-1, 1}} & /@ Range[2, 8]
num = 0;
Do[num++; Print[num];, ##] &[asdf]
```

or

```
Do[num++; Print[num];, Sequence@@asdf]
```

The iteration variables are `i[1]`...`i[8]`. The problem is that `Do` automatically encloses the arguments in an extra `{ }` which I can't seem to get around.

Comment: 1. `Do[num++; Print[num];, ##] & @@ asdf`  2. `Do[num++; Print[num];, Sequence @@ asdf // Evaluate]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps this will work for you.

```
num = 0;
With[{indxs = Sequence @@ ({i[#], -1, 1} & /@ Range[2, 8])},
  Do[num++; Print[num], indxs]]
```

Caution: evaluating the above code creates 2187 print cells.

In the case where it is important for you to store the iterator specification in a variable, you could write

```
num = 0;
indxs = Sequence @@ ({i[#], -1, 1} & /@ Range[2, 3]); 
Do[num++; Print[num], Evaluate @ indxs]
```

Comment: Thanks, so I think I understand that the issue has to do with the `Do` iterator having the `Hold` attribute, so why does using `With` not require the use of `Evaluate`?

Comment: @Kai. Because the first argument of `With` is evaluated and substituted into the `Do` expression before the argument evaluation of the `Do` expression itself, `With` is somewhat like the macro preprocessor of C/C++ in terms its place in the evaluation chain.